# How to make JavaScript image flip default to hover state on mobile

Tags: javascript, image, hover, onmouseover, flip

I have 6 images currently set up with an onmouseover image flip. I'd like to know if there's a straightforward way to make them static on the hovered image for mobile.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to test if JavaScript is disabled, and thus your `onmouseover` won't fire, you can use the `<noscript>` tag. But I'd sooner advise you to find a CSS `:hover` solution which would work with JavaScript disabled.